# Creating of external library of hibernate objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some web-project (Spring MVC + Hibernate). For hibernate objects I am using an annotations. For specific purpose I need to create a console application that should use the same objects as web-project. So I need to redefine it in a console application project.
I thought to create an axternal library (jar file) with hibernate objects and connect that library to each project that need it.
Is this a good solution? Is there some problem with hibernate objects in this solution? May be there are different solutions?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So , both the console application and web-project uses  the same Database ? If yes , it is a good solution as it allows code reuse .

If both applications have their own   hibernate entities , you have to update the entities in both applications if there are any update. If you make the  hibernate entities  as an library  , you only need to update the library once .